# springboot-javafx-support launchApp(AbstractJavaFxApplicationSupport, AbstractFxmlView, String[])

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, javafx

Hello I am using library called **springboot-javafx-support version 1.3.27**

*https://github.com/roskenet/springboot-javafx-support* by [roskenet](https://github.com/roskenet)

In my JavaFX project using Gradle, I encountered some problem regarding using the launchApp(.....) method if my project structure is like this

```
src
|-main
|-java
|   |-com.example
|     |-view 
|     |    |- SampleView.class
|     |    |- SampleController.class
|     |-launcher
|          |- ApplicationLauncher.class
|-resources
    |-com.example.view
          |-sample.fxml
```

ApplicationLauncher.class

```
import de.felixroske.jfxsupport.AbstractJavaFxApplicationSupport;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

 @SpringApplication
 public class ApplicationLauncher{
       launchApp(ApplicationLauncher.class,SampleView.class,args);
 }
```

SampleView.class

```
import de.felixroske.jfxsupport.AbstractFxmlView;
import de.felixroske.jfxsupport.FXMLView;

@FXMLView(bundle="com.vhl.practice.helloworld")
public class HelloworldView extends AbstractFxmlView {

}
```

when I try to run my ApplicationLauncher.class I get this kind of error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.SampleView' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:340)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1090)
    at de.felixroske.jfxsupport.AbstractJavaFxApplicationSupport.showView(AbstractJavaFxApplicationSupport.java:114)
    at de.felixroske.jfxsupport.AbstractJavaFxApplicationSupport.showInitialView(AbstractJavaFxApplicationSupport.java:105)
    at de.felixroske.jfxsupport.AbstractJavaFxApplicationSupport.lambda$start$2(AbstractJavaFxApplicationSupport.java:76)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$49(GtkApplication.java:139)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

If my project structure is some what shown below, My application runs without error

```
src
    |-main
    |-java
    |   |-com.example
    |     |-view 
    |     |    |-/empty/
    |     |    
    |     |-launcher
    |          |- ApplicationLauncher.class
    |          |- SampleView.class
    |          |- SampleController.class
    |-resources
        |-com.example.view
              |-sample.fxml
```

So my question is why I get **no qualifying bean type error** when I am calling class on different package outside the spring-boot starter class. Any suggestion how to deal with this?

And If some knows this library how is this different from just using

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main extends Application{

    private ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext;
    private Parent rootNode;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    int x = 0;
    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        springContext = SpringApplication.run(Main.class); //-- where spring-boot application starts
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Main.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(springContext::getBean);
        rootNode = fxmlLoader.load();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setScene(new Scene(rootNode));
        stage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        springContext.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use @ComponentScan("....") on your spring application

Comment: Yes, this could solve the problem. What I do instead is move my main class to the outermost part of my package so it can scan and detect any annotated classes.

Anyway thanks for answering.